# PasteBin API can't paste code with '&'

Tags: c#, api, pastebin

I'm using PASTEBIN api to paste soem C# code. All works fine except that when my code contains an '&', this sounds strange to me since I'm using `Uri.EscapeUriString`. Here the code that creates my payload:

```
private byte[] GetUploadData(string key, string s, string lang)
    {
        var payload = string.Join("&", new string[]
       {
           "api_option=paste"
           ,"api_dev_key=1234567890000000000000000000"
           ,"api_user_key="+login
           ,"api_paste_code="+Uri.EscapeUriString(s)
           ,"api_paste_expire_date=N"
            ,"api_paste_format="+lang
            ,"api_paste_name="+Uri.EscapeUriString(key)
            ,"api_paste_private = 0"

       }
        );
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
    }
```

when code contains a '&' it get truncated. 
What can be wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Uri.EscapeDataString instead